# Simple attempt to change font-color with AngularJS, why doesn't it work?

Tags: css, angularjs, styles

I'm trying to make a simple program.  The user types text into the text box, and it shows up below.  However, I also want the font-color to change based on what the user types into the "color" field.  Why doesn't this work?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="">



<textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30" ng-model="writing">
</textarea>
<span>    Color: <input type = "text" ng-model="marker_color"></span>
<br>
<br>

<div id = "whiteboard" ng-bind="writing" style="color:{{marker_color}}"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried flanking 'marker_color' with spaces, putting a semicolon after the variable, switching between 'font-color' and just 'color'...nothing seems to work.

I see a lot of questions about how to do this type of thing, but most of them seem to be using more advanced AngularJS.  This is very basic and it seems like it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You achieve like that

```
ng-style="{ 'color' : marker_color }"
```

Comment: Wow, so simple!  Thanks!